# Getting initials out of a list of names in python

Tags: python, list, slice

```
names=(input("Enter full names sperated by commas: "))
initials=list(names)
```

I want to grab the first and second initials of each name. The first and last name are separated by spaces. the next name is spaced by a comma.

Comment: Did you try reading the Python documentation?

Comment: Enter a people's names, separated by commas: Randall Alexander, Tony Leclerc, RoxAnn Stalvey, Walter Pharr
The initials are RA  TL  RS  WP.

Comment: thats what it should look like

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/). It's particularly useful at explaning basic concepts. Each built-in type (like string, list, etc) has its own page and most of their methods (functions) are shown at the bottom of the page. For your example, look for the _split_ method for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` module.

```
>>> name = input('Enter full names seperated by commas: ')
Enter full names seperated by commas: Randall Alexander, Tony Leclerc, RoxAnn Stalvey, Walter Pharr
>>> [x+y for (x,y) in re.findall(r'(?:^|,)\s*([A-Z])\w+\s+([A-Z])\w+', name)]
['RA', 'TL', 'RS', 'WP']
```

The above regex captures the first letter of each word. Since we used two capturing groups, the return type of `re.findall` function must be a list of tuple.  Joining each tuple elements inside a list comprehension will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like regular expression one could do something like:

```
>>> ii=[]
>>> s = raw_input('--> ')
--> Ronald Reagan, George Bush, Bill Clinton, George Walker Bush, Barrack Hussein Obama
>>> for pres in map(lambda i:i.split(),map(lambda p:p.strip(), s.split(','))):
...    ii.append(map( lambda p:p[0], pres ))
...
>>> map(lambda l:'.'.join(l),ii)
['R.R', 'G.B', 'B.C', 'G.W.B', 'B.H.O']
>>> for initials in  map(lambda l:'.'.join(l),ii):
...    print initials
...
R.R
G.B
B.C
G.W.B
B.H.O
```